# Measuring time in an if-statement

Tags: java, android, button, if-statement, time

I want the time start to count on the first click on the button. on the last click, it should give me the time between the first and the last click. In my code it says, `startTime cannot be resolved to a variable` when I want to get the `difference`.

here's the code.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time);
        Random r = new Random();
        RelativeLayout decorView = (RelativeLayout) start_time.getParent();
        int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();

        i++;

        /*  
        Random r = new Random();

        int x = r.nextInt(R.id.wrap_content);
        int y = r.nextInt(R.id.wrap_content);

        b.setX(x);  
        b.setY(y);
        */ 

        if (i == 1 ) {
            long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
            start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
        }
        if (i == 2 ) {
            start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
            start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
        }
        if (i == 3 ) {
            start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
            start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
        }
        if (i == 4 ) {
            start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
            start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
        }
        if (i == 5 ) {
            start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
            start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
        }
        if (i == 6 ) {
            start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
            start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
        }
        else if (i == 7) {
   long difference = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  - startTime;

        // here it says startTime cannot be resolved to a variable

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
        intent1.putExtra("time",difference);
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from

```
if (i == 1) {
    long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    ...
```

to

```
long startTime;
if (i == 1) {
    startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    ...
```

When you define a variable inside a block (in your case an if block), the scope of the variable is the block and cannot be used outside this block.

Edit:

Also, if I understand your code correctly, you need the time difference on the seventh click, so you can do:

```
else if (i == 7) {
    long difference = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  - startTime;

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
    intent1.putExtra("time",difference);

    finish();
}
```

Comment: Now I'm not getting a result, I mean, the string `intent1.putExtra("time",difference);` where the time should be in is empty

Comment: @Emanuel Graf I have edited my answer, I hope I have understood your problem

Comment: thanks. yes, I have changed it, but I'm still not getting the time.. :(

Comment: @Emanuel Graf What is the value of `difference` when your code reaches `intent1.putExtra("time",difference);`?

Comment: It should be the time...no? how can I check that? sorry for asking

Comment: I found it :) sorry. the value is 240337

Comment: @Emanuel Graf then you have your difference value set in the extras of your `Intent`. You can call `intent1.startActivity(intent);` to start your `MainScreen` sending the extras to it, or do whatever you want with it :)

Comment: `intent cannot be resolved to a variable` hope this is the last error, what did I wrong?  wow this is great. thank you

Comment: @Emanuel Graf my mistake, the correct line is `startActivity(intent1);`

Answer (score 1):

You have `startTime` declared in the first `if` statement

```
 if (i == 1 ) {
    long startTime =    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

so it is out of scope outside of that. Declare it sooner like at the beginning of the `onClick()`

```
public void onClick(View v) {

 textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//...
//Somewhere here
long startTime;
```

then just initialize it in your `if`

```
 if (i == 1 ) {
    startTime =    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Comment: it says `The local variable startTime may not have been initialized` a quickfix is `long startTime = 0;` but this is not working

Comment: If I initialize `long startTime = 0;` then I'm not getting a result.

Comment: Ah, yeah it will be reinitialized to 0 each time. Make it a member variable (outside of a method)

Comment: so i just put it after this `public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener{   long startTime;` right? but it still says it is uninitialized..

Comment: Yes put it there and initialize it `long startTime = 0;`

Comment: Now, there is again no time displayed,  I mean, the string intent1.putExtra("time",difference); where the time should be in is empty

Comment: Your original problem is fixed. You need to do a little debugging to see why that might be. We are getting way off the scope of this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72701/discussion-between-codemagic-and-emanuel-graf).